# Built-in way to flip ruby hash associations

Tags: ruby, hashmap

Assuming I have a ruby has with one-to-one correspondence, is there some built-in method to reverse associations in a ruby hash? I would prefer doing this without **explicitly** looping through the keys.

For example, suppose I have:

```
a = {1 => "Foo", 2 => "Bar"}
a.reverse_association
a # ---> {"Foo" => 1, "Bar" => 2}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use [`Hash#invert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert):

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2}
h.invert #=> {1 => :a, 2 => :b}
```